# No field mCollapsingTextHelper in class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout, typeface

Hello there I want to set the TextInputLayout font using the below code:

```
public class CustomFont {
    public static void setTypefaceToInputLayout(TextInputLayout inputLayout, String typeFace, Context context){

        final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), typeFace);

        inputLayout.getEditText().setTypeface(tf);
        try {
            // Retrieve the CollapsingTextHelper Field
            final Field collapsingTextHelperField = inputLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCollapsingTextHelper");
            collapsingTextHelperField.setAccessible(true);

            // Retrieve an instance of CollapsingTextHelper and its TextPaint
            final Object collapsingTextHelper = collapsingTextHelperField.get(inputLayout);
            final Field tpf = collapsingTextHelper.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTextPaint");
            tpf.setAccessible(true);

            // Apply your Typeface to the CollapsingTextHelper TextPaint
            ((TextPaint) tpf.get(collapsingTextHelper)).setTypeface(tf);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // Nothing to do
            Log.e("errorXYZ","error:::"+ignored.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The method is written in Java and I am calling it from the Kotlin as:

```
  CustomFont.setTypefaceToInputLayout(externalView.passwordTIL,"fonts/af/dragon.ttf",context!!)
```

I have been trying since last 24 Hours, and to some reason I need it at any cost to set the TextInputLayout font (the floating hint font actually)!

I am getting the following exception all the time:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mCollapsingTextHelper in class Landroid/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout; (declaration of 'android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout' appears in /data/app/com.ar.ere-2/base.apk:classes2.dex)
```

I have not idea about this exception, but for info I have enabled mutlidex in my gradle file. So should I exclude some files from Multidex lib? but how?

I have no idea at all!

Can somebody please review the situation please!

Comment: Which library and version are you using for the `TextInputLayout`?

Answer (score 1):

The `mCollapsingTextHelper` has been renamed to `collapsingTextHelper`

It might be the `mTextPaint` has been renamed to `textPaint`
Kindly check.

[source](https://medium.com/knowing-android/textinputlayout-with-drawable-without-the-padding-hint-4e7fcc8a95db)

Answer (score 0):

You are using reflection to access a field that's not there.

[TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html) has a [setTypeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#settypeface) method that can be used to change both the floating hint and any errors messages.